# How to disable keepalive in curl

Tags: networking, http, curl, keepalive

I'm trying to figure out how to consistently turn off keepalive across various client machines which are issuing HTTP requests via `curl`.

This is my target server:

```
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- 4.15.0-47-generic
- HA-Proxy version 1.8.19-1ppa1~bionic 2019/02/12
```

This is client 1 where from I'm issuing `curl` (vanilla installation):

```
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- 4.4.0-62-generic
- curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
```

This is client 2 where from I'm issuing `curl` (vanilla installation):

```
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- 4.15.0-20-generic
- curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
```

To turn off keepalive I've tried using `-H "Connection: close"`, `--no-keepalive` and `--keepalive-time 1` and only the first option seems to work but only from client 1.

On client 1 (Ubuntu 16) the connection is not left open but from client 2 (Ubuntu 18) the connection is left open until it times out. I confirm that either by looking at the target server's `watch -n 0.1 "netstat -na | fgrep CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS"` or by using `-vvv` on both clients, which on client 1 is always `* Closing connection 0` and on client 2 is always `* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact`.

The difference between client 1 and 2 are obviously the Ubuntu version and curl version. What is it that causes the the connection to be closed in client 1 but not in client 2?

I've also found out that if I change my target server to another machine running an old distro with an old apache httpd, whether I send out `Connection: close` or not doesn't make any difference and keepalive is always used from either of my 2 clients. So I suppose that the target server configuration also plays some role in that.

**Edit**:
To complicate things even further, if from client 1 and 2 I issue requests to the target server via `ab` then the connection is killed instantly. That is expected because `ab` uses `HTTP/1.0` and not `HTTP/1.1`. But then, if I target the old distro with apache then in both cases the connection remains open. Which means that, indeed, the receiving end plays a role as well.

**Edit 2**:
I grabbed all `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/` settings of both clients via:

```
for file in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/*
do
  echo "$file $(cat $file)"
done
```

and these can be found here:

- U16: https://pastebin.com/GcuuqhvA
- U18: https://pastebin.com/a2QWReFZ
- diff: https://pastebin.com/25Ccyz9h

Comment: Is there any tcp parameters changes between these 2 clients such as **net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries** ?

Comment: In both clients `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries` returns `6`.

Comment: @asktyagi: I've added all `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/` settings in the question.

Answer (score 6):

The --no-keepalive option is only useful for TCP keepalive packets, as mentioned in this archived thread on the curl website: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-04/0037.html

Sounds like you'll need to disable HTTP keepalive packets specifically, which would be done on your servers using keepalive_timeout 0; as mentioned in this stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924237/linux-curlnginx-cant-request-with-no-keepalive.

Sorry if the formatting is off, this is my first post :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your formatting is fine... Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 3):

Per https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/persist

> curl will always try to keep connections alive and reuse existing
> connections as far as it can.

Therefore, you cannot use it using the tools as they are.

As @pl-nowlan mentioned in their answer, the only way to do that would be on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -H "Connection: close"

Using -v (verbose mode) you should see the difference.

Answer (score -3):

you can use option --no-keepalive. See more at man curl

--no-keepalive
Disables the use of keepalive messages on the TCP connection, as by default curl enables them.

Note  that  this  is  the negated option name documented. You can thus use --keepalive to enforce keepalive.

Comment: please read the question. This option has been mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `man curl`. As I mention in the question I've tried that. Both client 1 and 2 leave the connection open when using `--no-keepalive`. I've found out that by using `-H "Connection: close"` at least kills the connection on client 1.